# How to pass multiple arguments in os.system() in python 2.7 (Python Script).

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.system

I am creating a python script where i needed to pass 2-3 arguments in os.system(). Suppose those commands/arguments are a,b. here A should execute first then B.
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: could you be more specific on what commands you want to use?

Comment: use `argparse` module

Comment: Are any of the answers what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the problem, you can just use the same commands as you would do on the command line. For instance:

```
import os
os.system("ls -l && echo \"hello\"")
```

Or if you want to execute the second command even though the first one failed:

```
import os
os.system("a ; b" )
```

Comment: Its not working. Here A is a ssh command which will log in to a remote system, then there B should execute.

Comment: In that case, adjust your question. This is completely unclear and for general commands my method would work. Perhaps you have to look into libraries that allow remote login!

Answer (score 1):

To get the argument :

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```